# Restate as 1-2/(3 f[])

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I strongly suspect that

`Sqrt[(9 + 2 q[5]^2 - 2 q[5] Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2])/(27 + 4 q[5]^2)]`

can be restated as

`Sqrt[1-2/3f[]]`

but I cannot see how I can make Mathematica even write it as `1-2/3f[x]`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Solve[Sqrt[(9 + 2 q[5]^2 - 2 q[5] Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2])/(27 + 4 q[5]^2)] ==
   Sqrt[1 - 2/3 f[]], q[5]]` Shows only Complex solutions

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you clarify?  If `f[1/Sqrt[3]]` is `(3 (9 + q[5]^2 + q[5] Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2]))/(27 + 4 q[5]^2)`, then you get that expression.  But I'm sure this is not what you mean.

Comment: Using @Freye's approach, I used `Reduce[Sqrt[(9 + 2 q[5]^2 - 2 q[5] Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2])/(27 + 4 q[5]^2)] == Sqrt[1 - 2/(3 + 3 q[5] f[])], f[] ]` which proposes an `f[ ]`, which simplifies to `1/9 (q[5] - Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2])` and I am working on that.

Comment: If you can convince yourself that it would be correct to square both sides then FullSimplify[Reduce[(9+2q[5]^2-2q Sqrt[6+q[5]^2])/(27+4q[5]^2)==1-2/3 f[x], f[x]]] might give you some information about f[x]

Comment: I am stuck at `Reduce[(9 + 2 q[5]^2 - 2 q[5] Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2])/(27 + 4 q[5]^2) == 1 - 2/(3 + q[5] (1 - 2/3) f[]), f[] ]` which proposes `f[g]=q[5] - Sqrt[6 + q[5]^2]` but that looks like it can become part of the pattern.